# SQL - Dejar registro repetidos con valor cero

Tags: sql

estoy practicando con sql y tengo el siguiente problema, tengo una base de datos con tres tablas:

La primera tabla se llama "Productos", sus datos son:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La segunda tabla  se llama "Pedido", sus datos son:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tercera tabla se llama "Auxiliar", sus datos son

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si realizo un inner join con las tres tablas descritas obtengo como resultado la siguiente tabla (valor = Precio X Cantidad):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema con esta tabla es que obtengo repetida la información en el campo venta, existe alguna forma de dejar en null o en cero esa información, para dejarla de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La query del inner join es:

```
SELECT auxiliar.Id_pedido, auxiliar.Id_Producto, auxiliar.cantida,
Productos.Producto, Productos.Precio, Pedido.cliente, Pedido.venta
FROM auxiliar
INNER JOIN Productos ON auxiliar.ID_Producto = Productos.ID_Producto
INNER JOIN Pedido ON auxiliar_Orden.ID_pedido = Pedido.ID_pedido
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, edita tu pregunta (enlace Editar bajo las etiquetas) y añade las consultas que has usado hasta ahora (las que generan los resultados que muyestras al final de la pregunta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero es el escenario:

```
Create table productos (id_producto int, Producto varchar(100), precio decimal (5,3))
Create table Pedido (id_pedido int, Cliente varchar(100), Venta decimal (5,3))
Create table Auxiliar(id_pedido int, id_producto int, Cantidad int)
go
Insert into Productos (id_producto, producto, precio)
values 
(1,'Auto',1.000),
(2,'Muñeca',2.000),
(3,'Oso',1.500);

Insert into Pedido(id_pedido, Cliente, Venta)
values
(1,'Jose',3.000),
(2,'Andrea',4.000),
(3,'Felipe',4.500),
(4,'Mario',5.000);

Insert into Auxiliar (id_pedido, id_producto, Cantidad)
values
(1,1,1),
(1,2,1),
(2,2,2),
(3,1,1),
(3,2,1),
(3,3,1),
(4,1,4),
(4,1,1);
go
```

En función del motor SQL, puedes utilizar el operador LAG para obtener datos sobre la fila anterior.

En SQL Server puede ser tal que:

```
;with c as (
Select auxiliar.id_pedido
     , auxiliar.id_producto
     , auxiliar.cantidad
     , productos.producto
     , productos.precio
     , pedido.cliente
     , Pedido.Venta
     , lag(pedido.venta,1) over(partition by auxiliar.id_pedido order by auxiliar.id_pedido, auxiliar.id_producto) nxt
     
       From auxiliar
            Inner Join productos On auxiliar.id_producto = productos.id_producto
            Inner Join pedido On auxiliar.id_pedido = pedido.id_pedido
)
select c.id_pedido, c.id_producto, c.Cantidad, c.Producto, c.precio, c.Cliente, 
case when c.Venta = c.nxt then '' else CAST(c.Venta AS varchar(6)) end as venta
from c;
```

Una forma muy didáctica de hacerlo es leer la información en una tabla de expresión común, y le aplicas la función de ventana LAG, para esa columna, y así obtener el valor anterior. Luego en la salida utilizas una expresión case para devolver los datos en función de si el anterior tenía lo mismo que el actual, devuelves lo que consideres oportuno. (null o '').

[image: Resultados]

[Sql Server Lag](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/09/11/lag-y-lead-siguiente-y-anterior/)

[MySql Lag](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-lag-function/)

Comment: La respuesta esta perfecta!!!!

Desconocía que existía el operador "LAG", muchísimas gracias

Comment: @AlexisMolinaBarrios recuerda marcar como respuesta usando el "check"

Answer (score 0):

Solo para complementar la respuesta de Javi, dejo el siguiente código *SQL* para crear la base, las tablas, sus relaciones y los datos a ingresar en la base:

```
create database Ejemplo

use Ejemplo

Create table Productos (id_producto int primary key, Producto varchar(20), precio int)
Create table Pedido (id_pedido int primary key , Cliente varchar(20), Venta int)
Create table Auxiliar(id_pedido int, id_producto int, Cantidad int)

ALTER TABLE Auxiliar ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_pedido) REFERENCES Pedido (id_pedido);
ALTER TABLE Auxiliar ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES Productos (id_producto);

use Ejemplo

go
Insert into Productos (id_producto, producto, precio)
values 
(1,'Auto',1000),
(2,'Muñeca',2000),
(3,'Oso',1500);

Insert into Pedido(id_pedido, Cliente, Venta)
values
(1,'Jose',3000),
(2,'Andrea',4000),
(3,'Felipe',4500),
(4,'Mario',5000);

Insert into Auxiliar (id_pedido, id_producto, Cantidad)
values
(1,1,1),
(1,2,1),
(2,2,2),
(3,1,1),
(3,2,1),
(3,3,1),
(4,1,4),
(4,1,1);
go
```